# Amcharts 4 heat legend - how to position below the map

Tags: legend, heatmap, amcharts4

The heat legend shown in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/yvdwrR) is placed (overlaid) on top of the map. I would like to have it positioned below the map, in a legend or footer area, but cannot find any options to do. The relevant code we have tried so far is:

```
var heatLegend = chart.chartContainer.createChild(am4maps.HeatLegend);
heatLegend.valign = "bottom";
```

But this simply obscures the bottom third of the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use external container. 
Add another legend div to your html.

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="legenddiv"></div>
```

Then change your js code

```
let legendContainer = am4core.create("legenddiv", am4core.Container);
legendContainer.width = am4core.percent(100);
legendContainer.height = am4core.percent(100);
// add heat legend
var heatLegend = legendContainer.createChild(am4maps.HeatLegend);
```

For more information check this out:
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-legend-in-an-external-container/